Laravel 11 mix to vite : Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
I'm using Laravel 11 mix and I have a problem with Alpine which is loaded 2 times when I connect on my website in local. If it's possible, I prefer to stay in mix I already tried to go on Laravel vite but I have a problem with my jQuery and Bootstrap.
Here is the error I have:

livewire.js?id=87e1046f:9882 Detected multiple instances of Alpine running

and here is my code:
app.js:
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();

require('./sb-admin-2');

bootstrap.js:
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    //window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    //require('jquery.easing')(window.jQuery);

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {
}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

and finally my webpack.mix.js:
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-purgecss');


mix.webpackConfig({
    stats: {
        children: true
    }
});

mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .js("resources/js/bootstrap.js", "public/js")
    .sass( "resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
    .purgeCss(
);


I saw on forum that is possible to solve it by going on Laravel vite but do you know if there are other options?
I have these versions:
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
"alpinejs": "^3.8.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"npm": "^10.8.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1"


Do you have Livewire installed?

yes, i have the 3.5.1

Livewire 3 comes bundled with AlpineJS, so unless you require to, you simply don't have to manually start AlpineJS.
In your case, you can simply remove the following snippet entirely:
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();

You can read more about it here.
